# artifacts appearing in VT100 raw mode

Tags: c++, termios, vt100

considering this code:

```
#include<cstdio>
extern"C"{
#include<termios.h>
#include<unistd.h>
}
int main(){
    termios termattr_bak;
    termios termattr;
/*  switch to raw mode*/
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&termattr_bak);
    termattr.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;
    termattr.c_iflag &= ~unsigned(INLCR|ICRNL|IXON|IXOFF);
    termattr.c_lflag &= ~unsigned(ICANON|ECHO|ECHOK|ECHOE|ECHONL|ISIG|IEXTEN);
    termattr.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    termattr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&termattr);
/*  */
    printf("test\r\n");
    printf("test\r\n");
    printf("test\r\n");
    fflush(stdout);
/*  restore terminal attributes*/
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&termattr_bak);
    return 0;
}
```

the program compiles with `g++ main.cc` and works just as expected around 80% of the time with this trace:

```
test
test
test
```

but sometimes, randomly, the trace is like this:

```
test

test

test
```

or this:

```
test
    
    test
        
        test
```

or even those above with capital letters (!?) like

```
TEST
TEST
TEST
```

and so on.

I just run the same program again and again in the same terminal with randomly the different behaviors above.
It is the same under both gnome-terminal and xterm.

I tried to `fflush` and/or `tcflush` and/or `tcdrain` at different locations with no success.

What is happening here and how do I prevent this ?

EDIT:

It seems that `gcc -Og main.cc` produces a different code that works correctly. So it looks to me like something is beeing broken by the optimisations, which means I am doing something wrong with the code which only shows up when optimized (but What ?), or less likely there is a bug with GCC

EDIT2:

As SergeBallesta mentionned, I was not initializing the termios structure before use, which was leading the random problems above.
This one works :

```
#include<cstdio>
extern"C"{
#include<termios.h>
#include<unistd.h>
}
int main(){
    termios termattr_bak;
    termios termattr{};//<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< zero-init the struct
/*  switch to raw mode*/
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO,&termattr_bak);
    termattr.c_iflag |= IGNBRK;
    termattr.c_iflag &= ~unsigned(INLCR|ICRNL|IXON|IXOFF);
    termattr.c_lflag &= ~unsigned(ICANON|ECHO|ECHOK|ECHOE|ECHONL|ISIG|IEXTEN);
    termattr.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    termattr.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&termattr);
/*  */
    printf("test\r\n");
    printf("test\r\n");
    printf("test\r\n");
    fflush(stdout);
/*  restore terminal attributes*/
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO,TCSAFLUSH,&termattr_bak);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: Shouldn't there a ```struct``` keyword before `termios`? And is this ```~unsigned(INLCR|ICRNL|IXON|IXOFF)``` supposed to be a cast? That doesn't look like a valid statement to me, nor does it compile.

Comment: Indeed, this is compiled as c++ as you probably understood

Comment: What does "80% of the time" mean? Do you test in the same terminal all the time? Do you test with different terminals? I would assume the terminals have different settings how they handle end of line characters.

Comment: @Gerhardh it is the very same terminal, I just run the program again and again

Comment: No, I did not. Do not tag C when your question is about another language.

Comment: Isn't `termattr` uninitilized ?

Comment: You correctly initialize `termattr_bak` with the current attributes, but `termattr` is used without prior initialization leading to UB. It sometimes does not contain *erratic* values and everything looks fine, but UB is UB. Just add `termattr = termattr_bak;` before using it...

Comment: @SergeBallesta You're right, that was the problem... I can't believe I've been struggling in such a basic bug. Thank you a lot for spotting it

Answer (score 1):

You should not be *zero*-initializing the termios structure. Get the current settings, *make a copy*, then adjust it for raw mode using `cfmakeraw()`.

```
#define _DEFAULT_SOURCE
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct termios initial_settings;
struct termios raw_settings;

void finalize()
{
  printf( "\033[?1049l" );
  tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &initial_settings );
}

bool initialize()
{
  if (tcgetattr( STDIN_FILENO, &initial_settings ) < 0) 
    return false;

  raw_settings = initial_settings;
  cfmakeraw( &raw_settings );

  // adjust raw_settings if needed here          //
  // for example, for non-blocking, polling I/O: //
  // raw_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 0;
  // raw_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;

  if (tcsetattr( STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &raw_settings ) < 0) 
    return false;

  // more initializations here, like: //
  printf( "\033[?1049h" );  // alternate screen buffer mode
  ...

  // Make sure to undo all the changes at program exit
  atexit( finalize );
}
```